# iPhone Call Information

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to program a PhoneGap Plugin for by clicking the app.  I'm only looking to get the phone number and call duration of the call.  Does anyone have any information of coding this either in cross platform or native Objective-C?

Comment: Note: to future "vote to reopeners" - I recommend you read the answer given for this question before voting...

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible under any version of iOS on a non-jailbroken device, and doing any type of manipulation of any kind to obtain this information won't be accepted in the app store.